# IPhone picture metadata

Tags: iphone, photos

I am trying to find a way to organize picture metadata in my iPhone. By default, it adds location and time data, so that the photos are easily searchable on the phone.

I would like to be able to add custom tags, such as for people. Ideally, I would like to have a face recognition tool that learns from existing tags and helps tagging new pictures.

The metadata should be written in the photos in EXIF, IPTC and/or XMP format, so that other tools on my computer will recognize them. It seems that this is not happening even for the location data, that I can only see on the phone.

Is there some application that can help me tag and organize pictures as above?

Comment: Photos.app on the Mac does all that. You've tagged your question with that. Could you clarify whether you are looking for how to do it on Photos, whether you are looking for a different/better Mac app, or whether you mean on the iPhone itself, or a Windows PC?

Comment: There are a few things I was not able to do with Photos. One is tagging people, in particular with suggestions coming from face recognition. Another one is adding custom tags, such as "holidays". Finally, the location information is there, but I can only see it on the phone. I would like to have it in a standard format inside the picture itself, so that other tools on the computer will see it. I don't have a preference on using Photos or a third party app

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I do not have a Mac. I would like to do this on the phone itself

Comment: maybe this - [PhotoTime - Automatic Face Sorting & Keywords Tagging for Your Moments](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phototime-automatic-face-sorting/id846435251?mt=8)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that PhotoTime sends pictures remotely in order to tag them. This is not acceptable - I need something that will work locally on the phone

Comment: My guess then is, as it's perfectly possible in Photos on the Mac, it needs more horsepower than you can get from a phone